# Android 6 Capture Image and Crop And get URI

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Hello I use this code to take image (after take image the image was saved on camera folder automatic)
All work great in all version (18,19,20,21,22) until 23
Then the app crash after taking picture

```
Intent cameraintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraintent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

and in onActivityResult I try to crop image, but the app crash
I understand that the image even not saved after taking image.

What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you need to incorporate the new android runtime permissions.
More information here: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.